# Why should Dasein be authentic when one knows that he/she will be responsible for his/her actions when he chooses authenticity over inauthenticity?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, existentialism, heidegger, self

Answers except "to know about being yourself" are really appreciated because this is the question itself. What should I strive to know about myself when I am happy with my life right now, not making decisions for my own self.

Comment: Authentic Dasein simply responds to a "call". One does not choose authenticity over inauthenticity; one merely has fleeting moments in which the call can be responded to or not. But even those who respond to the call inevitably sink back into inauthenticity in their average-everydayness. The "responsibility" at issue is not the usual concept, but rather responsibility for neglecting one's authentic self. So you are already responsible in your inauthenticity, you just use the meaningless distractions of the They to flee from responsibility. Happiness is not the issue.